Visual Studio - Debug tests - `Aborted: Exit code is -42`
I have an old project I try to update. It is based on ASP.NET Zero 6.5.0.
The Tests are based on Xunit. Since an unknown time, when I run a test in Debug, Visual Studo tells me Aborted: Exit code is -42. When I run the test withotu debugger, they succeed or fail normally.
I have another project based on a recent ASP.NET Zero which has no problem running tests in debug.
I tried to update the NuGets and the .NET environment.
I have the same problem with Rider.
